# Lucene exact match for facets drill down

Tags: java, lucene

I am wondering is there a way in **Lucene** to search the facet result string. When i search for the first time the fetched results are as follows.

1. Paris
2. Paris
3. Paris East
4. Paris West

The facet results are
1. Paris(2)
2. Paris East(1)
3. Paris West(1)

Now if I choose Paris in the filter, I should get only the results for "Paris". My search query is something like this.
Query = (city:"Paris") and P

This term fetches all the 4 records again since the word *Paris* exist in all the 4 records. Is there anyway I can filter out the other two records and match the records which have just the word "Paris"?

Comment: do you want to do that in lucene or in solr?

Comment: in lucene java implementation

Comment: in general answer is - yes, you could do a facet search in Lucene

Comment: I am already doing the facet search which returns the count. but the next time when i choose "Paris" from the facet search, I need to search for the records matching "paris" which I couldnt achieve since it also fetches me the all the 4 records.

Comment: try FacetsConfig config.setHierarchical("$facet", false);